# getting the equation numbering right using align and a long equation that splits

Tags: align, amsmath

So I've got a system of equations.  One equation is very long.  I want them all aligned, but I want the long equation to split over two lines.

```
\begin{align}
   \theta &= \theta(t-1) -p \theta(t-1) +p
             \frac{\hat{\psi}'(\theta(t-1))}{\ave{K}} +p \phi_R(0)\nonumber\\
          &\qquad + (1-p)(1-\theta(t-1))\\
   R   &= R(t-1)+I(t-1) 
\end{align}
```

As it stands, the equation for `\theta` spans two lines and is numbered on the second line.  I'd like the number to be centered (rather like split appears to do).  I haven't found a good way to do this.

Comment: Use `aligned` inside `equation`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`split` ought to work inside `align`, but it has some problems; a trick solves the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\newcommand{\ave}[1]{\langle #1\rangle}% <--- guess

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\mathllap{\theta}
  &= \theta(t-1) -p \theta(t-1) +p
     \frac{\hat{\psi}'(\theta(t-1))}{\ave{K}} +p \phi_R(0)\\
  &\qquad + (1-p)(1-\theta(t-1))\\
\end{split}
\\[1.5ex]
R &= R(t-1)+I(t-1)
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Some space is needed to make clearer what the numbers refer to, in my opinion.

[image]

Comment: great guess on \ave - nailed it.  Can you tell me why mathllap is needed?  I see it fixes the alignment, but it's not clear to me how.

Comment: @Joel I'd like to know, too. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to use the `aligned` environment, which acts as a single line for the purposes of equation numbering, alignment inside other environments, etc. You'll also want to remove the `\nonumber`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
   \theta &= \theta(t-1) -p \theta(t-1) +p
             \frac{\hat{\psi}'(\theta(t-1))}{K} +p \phi_R(0)\\
          &\qquad + (1-p)(1-\theta(t-1))\\
   R   &= R(t-1)+I(t-1) 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

it's possible to use `aligned` within `align`, as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
 \theta & =
\begin{aligned}[t]
   & \! \theta(t-1) -p \theta(t-1) +p
             \frac{\hat{\psi}'(\theta(t-1))}{K} +p \phi_R(0)\\
          &\qquad + (1-p)(1-\theta(t-1))\\
\end{aligned}\\
   R   &= R(t-1)+I(t-1) 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

two things to note here:

- to get the top line of the `aligned` block even with the left side,
  it's necessary to specify `[t]`.
- for reasons lost in the mists of time, an `aligned` block starts with
  `\,`, and this must be reversed with the negative equivalent, `\!`.
  (i didn't bother doing that on the second line, since it would probably
  not be obvious in the presence of the `\qquad`.)